# Why am I getting such slow transfer rate over wired LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have a Linksys WRT400N. Im trying to copy 400GB of data over LAN from one PC to another. Im getting 7-8MB/s over wireless AND wired. I have 10/100/1000 network cards in all PCs.

Anything I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linksys WRT400N does **NOT** have Gigabit LAN support.

That is your bottleneck.

Comment: Yes. If it's a one-off and physically possible, you should get Gigabit Ethernet speeds by directly connecting the PCs together (possibly needing a crossover cable). Or you could temporarily use a cross-over Ethernet coupler instead of the Linksys switch. But the ultimate solution is probably a switch upgrade...

Answer (score 1):

It's because the HDD Speed so you can't do anything.

Comment: The computer on which everything is offloaded to has a RAID5 array, which is capable of 100+ MB/s.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the adapters used within the computers, I work with many different sorts and find anything from 7-12MB/s normal on a 100Mb network. (remember, 8 Megabyes a second is 64 megabits a second)

As others have said, your router is not gigabit compatible, so it will most likely be falling back to a standard 100Mb speed.

If I was you, I would test copying to another machine and then bypassing the current one and copying directly from the other two just to test out your network and see what one has the slower card.

Apart from that, I typically find, if I need to do a really big transfer urgently (>100GB) I usually just rip out the hard drive and put it in a spare dock or internal connection and copy it as it can turn a job from a few hours in to a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other network devices in the mix? If there is a hub that could be your problem. A hub will slow down all ports to the speed of the lowest common denominator, so if it's connected and passing data between you and your router, and there is an active 10MB connection to the hub, your router can only submit the data as fast as it's being received. A slow hard drive could also be a bottleneck.

What category cable are you using? This will also have an effect.

Edit: As mentioned, the router isn't gigabit capable.

Comment: Nope, just 3 PCs on wired, and 1 PC on wireless. Network printer as well. Everything is connected directly to the router with CAT5 (or 6, Im not sure) cables.